# React DevTools Hooks not editable

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I'm using React 16.8.x and the latest version of the React DevTools. In some cases, I'm able to inspect and modify hooks like `useState` no problem. But in other cases, the hooks appear to be *read only* - I can't modify them from the dev tools. Clicking on them, there is no way to make any changes to their values.

Is there any rhyme or reason for why I can edit hooks from the dev tools sometimes but not others?

[image]

Comment: I also have this issue. In one project, I can edit state values in class components, but not hooks (useState) in functional components. I'm using React 16.8.6 and React DevTools Chrome Extension 4.2.1.